# ASP.Net Linq to Entities: An attempt to attach an auto-named database failed

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq-to-entities, connection-string

The problem is that the path to my database shown in the error below is incorrect.  I cannot find where that path is set as it is not in the settings or in any of the project files.  What am I missing:

The error:

> An attempt to attach an auto-named database for file H:\FoxCityGuide\FoxCityGuide\App_Data\Restaurants.mdf failed.

The path to the database:

> H:\FoxCityGuide\FoxCityGuide\Restaurants.mdf

**app.config**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <configSections></configSections>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="RestaurantsEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Restaurants.csdl|res://*/Restaurants.ssdl|res://*/Restaurants.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=SFP;attachdbfilename=|DataDirectory|\Restaurants.mdf;integrated security=True;multipleactiveresultsets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Please show us your connection string.

Comment: My magic mirror is showing the mysterious identifier |DataDirectory|

Comment: I have added the connection string.

Comment: Oh, yeah! Magic mirror does it again!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

2 options here.

1. Move your .mdf file into the App_Data folder as that is where |DataDirectory| is pointing.
2. Update your connection string to point at the .mdf file in its current location by editing the 'attachdbfilename=' value of your config.

Comment: Option 3 - modify the value of DataDirectory at run time